# how to roll out an image by diagonal in css3?

Tags: css, animation, transition

I'm working on a splash screen where I'm supposed to animate the transition of a logo from the center to the top left of the screen.  with roll out CS3 effect I have done this but I want to move it to the top left

```
    .animated { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes rollOut { 
    0% { 
        opacity: 1; 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); 
    } 
    100% { 
        opacity: 0; 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotate(120deg); 
    } 
} 
@keyframes rollOut { 
    0% { 
        opacity: 1; 
        transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); 
    } 
    100% { 
        opacity: 0; 
        transform: translateX(100%) rotate(120deg); 
    } 
} 
.rollOut { 
    -webkit-animation-name: rollOut; 
    animation-name: rollOut; 
}
```

so how I can combine between transition and animation in css to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Here, you also need to specify `right`, `left` and `top` properties in your animation so as to move the logo from the center to the top-left.  Also you need to add `translateY` to your animation.

```
.animated { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
    /* to center */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes rollOut { 
    0% { 
        opacity: 1; 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(0deg); 
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        } 
    100% { 
        opacity: 0; 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px) translateY(-100%) rotate(720deg); 
        right: 100%;
        top: 0;
        } 
} 
@keyframes rollOut { 
    0% { 
        opacity: 1; 
        transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotate(0deg); 
        right: 0;
        top: 50%; 
        } 
    100% { 
        opacity: 0; 
        transform: translateX(-100px) translateY(-100%) 
        right: 100%;
        top: 0;
        } 
} 
.rollOut { 
-webkit-animation-name: rollOut; 
animation-name: rollOut; 
}
```

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJEKyv